# Using typescript, is it possible to infer object keys from function argument values?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Take this string parsing function as an example.

```
  
  const { a, b } = parseString({
    string, 
    mapping: [{
      param: 'a',
      ...
    },{
      param: 'b',
      ...
    }]
```

Can i make typescript be aware that the only available keys should be 'a' and 'b'?

These are the types that I currently have.

```
interface ParseStringArgs {
    string: string;
    mapping: {
        start: string | null;
        end: string | null
        param: string;
    }[];
}
```

And my attempt at making it read the param key value.
Which obviously does not work now as it is (correctly) reading `param: string;` from the `ParseStringArgs` interface above.

```
export function parseString({ string, mapping }) {

...

    type ParamKey = typeof mapping[number]['param'];
    const result: Record<ParamKey, string> = {};

    ... some logic to populate result

    return result
```

Now the result of the `parseString` is `Record<string, string>`

Is it possible to make the return type of the function `Record<'a' | 'b', string>`?

Comment: Just make `param` `a | b` instead of `string`?

Comment: Things don’t become generic merely by using `typeof`; you need to explicitly declare generic type parameters. I’ll say more once I get off mobile, if nobody else gets here first.

Comment: The minimal change I can make to your code to get it working is [shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NloRew). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?